WKB Approximation of the Quasinormal Mode Spectrum of the Poschl-Teller (PT) Potential
In Black Hole Spectroscopy, it is well known that the Pöschl-Teller (PT) potential behaves approximately, or similarly to the more complicated Regge-Wheeler (RW) Potential.
The WKB Approximation has been extensively applied to RW to calculate its quasi-normal mode spectrum, but I have not seen anything in the literature applying it to the PT potential.
Has this been done, if so what does the approximation yield, and if not - is there some technical challenge that prevents its solution?

Voting to re-open. The question as is focussed fine. It asks the simple question has the QNM spectrum of the PT potential been determined using the WKB approximation? If not, why not? The is a reasonable question.

Okay so this question was really bugging me so I spent the afternoon learning how to do the approximation.
The general Poschl-Teller Potential is $V(x) = \frac{V_o}{\cosh^2(\alpha \cdot (x-x_0))} $
I take $ V_0 = 1, \alpha =1, x_0 = 0 \ \ \ \  \rightarrow  \ \ \ \ V(x) = \frac{1}{\cosh^2(x)} = \rm{sech}^2(x)$
Schutz and Will derive a general first order WKB approximation for QNMs:
$ \frac{Q_0}{\sqrt{2Q_0''}} = i(n+\frac{1}{2})$
This expands to:
$ \frac{w^2-\text{sech}^2(x)}{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{2 \text{sech}^4(x)-4 \tanh ^2(x) \text{sech}^2(x)}} = i(n+\frac{1}{2}) $
I evaluate at the peak of the potential, $x=0$, and solve for w taking the negative solution:
$ w = -\sqrt[4]{-1} \sqrt{2 n+(1-i)} $
I also reflect it across the imaginary axis to get the following spectrum, (vertical axis is the Im(w), and horizontal axis is Re(w)):

Compare this against the analytical derivation included by Berti, Cardoso, and Starinets:
$ \omega = \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4}}-\frac{1}{2} i (2 n+1) $
Reflecting this as well yields the following spectrum, (again vertical axis is the Im(w), and horizontal axis is Re(w)):

As is known the first order WKB is not terribly acurate, the fundamental mode is close, $-1.09868 - 0.45509i$ vs $-0.866025 - 0.5i$, but the asymptotic behavior is different, and there is significant deviation in the real value for the overtones.

Schrödinger operators with reflectionless Pöschl-Teller potentials arise in the study of SUSY chains of one-dimensional non-linear field theories labeled by $N$. The two first members of the family are the sine-Gordon model and the $\phi^4$-theory. The spectrum consists of $N-1$ bound states and a tower of continious modes. Such models are usually soved using the WKB-method. It also arises as Tachyon potential in the (guessing closed) bosonic string theory.
Barton Zwiebach JHEP09(2000)028 equation 2.15 is the chain I talked about.
A. Alonso-Izquierdo, J. Mateos Guilarte, On a family of (1+1)-dimensional scalar field theory models: Kinks, stability, one-loop mass shifts, Annals of Physics, Volume 327, Issue 9,2012

Can you provide a link to some of the relevant literature? I'm very curious to see the methods and results. In Black hole Spectroscopy there are analytical solutions so I'm curious how the implementation is different in string theory

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@RudyJD I added some references

It's worth noting the PNM Pöschl-Teller equation has a repulsive potential and so has no bound states. It's still exactly solvable, so I am not sure why you would want to study an approximate  method --- unless of course your interest is in the accuracy of wkb.

@mikestone I am interested in two reasons, 1 for a heuristic example to better learn how to apply the wkb method for QNMs, and 2 to see how accurate the WKB method is against an analytically solvable example. In the literature I have sometimes read that WKB is sommetimes "more accurate than one would expect".
For better context I am an undergraduate research assistant in the field of black hole spectroscopy. The team I am on specializes in the continued fraction method, and is not really familiar with the WKB method. Also can you explain the significance of PT being "repulsive"?
